# Robust clustered standard errors for ordered probit

Tags: r, regression

Is there a package or snippet of code for calculating robust standard errors and clustered robust standard errors for ordered probit (oprobit) models in R?

Most approaches seems constrained to GLMs or LMs.  polr objects seems to be arranged differently, so that could be what is interfering with using these to calculate standard errors.